# Arrays in Oracle 11

Tags: arrays, oracle11g

I would like to put the items from one table into an array in another table using  oracle 11.

For example, if I have the table A and table B

A.

```
   ID other
   A   343
   B   765
```

B

```
  ID  I_want
   A    Y1
   A    Y2
   A    Y3
   B    N2
   B    N1
```

I would like to get a table

```
   ID other   I_want
   A   343   [Y1, Y2, Y3]
   B   765   [N1, N2]
```

And if I have a table with a column containing arrays, how could I select the rows that have a specific item  of the list

Comment: Why do you want to store data like that - what purpose will it solve or what advantage do you think it gives you over your existing tables? it'll be really hard to work with... Apart from extracting information from it, what will you do if a row is added to table B for an existing ID? (Also, do you mean a varray, a nested table, or something else?)

Comment: Why do you think you need to denormalize your data?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is bad practice as this violates 1st normal form in database design. 
[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) 
Do a little searching to find out why this is a bad idea and why it will cause you trouble down the road, especially if you intend to work with the individual values.